# jquery reset the timer on every click timer is working very fast

Tags: jquery

I have set the count down timer of 3 seconds when it is zero displays alert , when click on it again before setting it to 0 the timer is working very fast.

```
$(".change-word").click(function(e) {
    $(".countdown").html("0");
    $(".countdown").html("3");
    var doUpdate = function() {
        $('.countdown').each(function() {
            var count = parseInt($(this).html());
            if (count !== 0) {
                $(this).html(count - 1);
            } else {
                alert("zero");
            }
        });
    };
    setInterval(doUpdate, 1000);
});
```

**This is the html**

```
<div class="countdown">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear interval on every click and when counter reaches 0. 
See this example:

```js
let interval;
$(".change-word").click(function(e) {
  //$(".countdown").html("0");
  $(".countdown").html("3");
  clearInterval(interval);
  var doUpdate = function() {
    $('.countdown').each(function() {
      var count = parseInt($(this).html());
      if (count !== 0) {
        $(this).html(count - 1);
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
        alert("zero");
      }
    });
  };
  interval = setInterval(doUpdate, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countdown">3</div>

<div class='change-word'>
  Change word
</div>
```

Comment: that's what I need let me try this

Answer (score 0):

When the timer hits 0 you do not:

- Set a new value to the .countdown div
- Stop the setInterval

This way it always loops every 1000ms, even if you do not click "Ok" on the alert, that's why it seems it goes "faster".

If you replace the alert with a `console.log(count)` you'll see it will write 0 every second.

```js
$(".change-word").click(function(e) {
    $(".countdown").html("0");
    $(".countdown").html("3");
    var doUpdate = function() {
        $('.countdown').each(function() {
            var time = new Date().getMinutes() +":"+ new Date().getSeconds();
            console.log(time);
            var count = parseInt($(this).html());
            if (count !== 0) {
                $(this).html(count - 1);
            } else {
                console.log("zero");
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        });
    };
    var interval = setInterval(doUpdate, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countdown">3</div>
<button class="change-word">Go</div>
```

Comment: Can you make the code with it so it will be understandable

Comment: Sure, I updated the answer, as you can see it ticks once per second :)

Comment: Balastrong I need the speed of timer should be constant , if I click again and again on the button it is working very fast

Comment: It's not faster, it's duplicated. You need to put a `clearInterval()` to stop this loop otherwise everytime you hit the button you'll add one more "timer" that ticks every second.